# BeautifulSoup .find() gives TypeError

Tags: python, unicode, find, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I get this error when running my script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grabber_test.py", line 45, in <module>
    print child.find(class_ = "tip")
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

Here's the part of script forcing this error:

```
for games in last_games:
    print "Your Champion: %s" % (games.find("div", class_ = "championName").string)
    print "Your KDA: %s/%s/%s" % (games.find("span", class_ = "kill").string, games.find("span", class_ = "death").string, games.find("span", class_ = "assist").string)
    team1 = games.find("div", class_ = "teamId-100")
    team2 = games.find("div", class_ = "teamId-200")
    for player1 in team1:
        for child in player1:
            print type(child)
            print child
            print child.find(class_ = "tip")
```

The .find() method is working fine in the first four times calling it but not after that.

**type(child)** gives **"unicode"**

I know that I can't call .find() on "unicode", but why is it appearing here and not before and how can I solve it?

**Edit:**
Here is the full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding=utf8
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

global name
global url
#name = raw_input("Summoner name? ")
url = str("http://euw.op.gg/summoner/userName=gotballsbro")
print url

global driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

#URL öffnen
response = driver.page_source
#verarbeitete URL in BeautifulSoup zur Weiterverarbeitung öffnen
global soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
print type(soup)

last_games = soup.findAll("div", class_ = "GameSimpleStats")

for games in last_games:
    print "Your Champion: %s" % (games.find("div", class_ = "championName").string)
    print "Your KDA: %s/%s/%s" % (games.find("span", class_ = "kill").string, games.find("span", class_ = "death").string, games.find("span", class_ = "assist").string)
    team1 = games.find("div", class_ = "teamId-100")
    team2 = games.find("div", class_ = "teamId-200")
    for player1 in team1:
        for child in player1:
            print type(child)
            print child
            print child.find(class_ = "tip")








driver.close()
```

I made the vars global, because it's a test file of my bigger script, where I use defs.

**Edit2:**
I edited the forcing error part into:

```
last_games = soup.findAll("div", class_ = "championIcon rawRectImage tip")
for games in last_games:
    print games["title"]
```

and now it's working :)

Comment: You should provide the html and an [MCVE] that would reproduce your problem.

Comment: don't put the solution (the answer) into your question. You could [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over an individual element (a child tag of the `<div class="teamId-100">` element); that element can contain both other elements and *text nodes*:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div>
...     Some text
...     <span>Another element</span>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> list(soup.find('div'))
['\n    Some text\n    ', <span>Another element</span>, '\n']
```

If you want to loop over *just* the *tags*, use `team1.find_all()`:

```
for player1 in team1.find_all():
    for child in player1.find_all():
```

Demo:

```
>>> soup.find('div')
<div>
    Some text
    <span>Another element</span>
</div>
>>> soup.find('div').find_all()
[<span>Another element</span>]
```